# How can I sum up sub-datarecords in a calculated field?

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm building a little Music Database with following tables:

[image: Tables with relations]

I would like to sum up the total count of tracks in the Table 'albums' as calculated field.
I created a Query with SQL that groups to albumtitles and shows the count of songs related to those albumtitles:

```
SELECT albums.AlbumTitle AS AlbumTitel, Count(songs.PK_songs_ID) AS TotalSongs
FROM songs INNER JOIN albums ON albums.PK_albums_ID = songs.FK_album_ID
GROUP BY albums.AlbumTitle;
```

That query works fine, but I don't know how to get the total count calculated in a calculated field. I need this field to be able to check in a formular if the tracklist is complete (the formular shows the artist and in a sub-form a list of all albums from this artist).

So, how do I get the 'TotalSongs' field in 'albums' working?

Comment: You named the TotalTracks field as TotalSongs in the SQL query.

Comment: yes, but that doesn't really matter as long as I'm using only one name in my whole query. Nevertheless I changed it now.